# Shorten data table keys preserving uniqueness

Tags: mysql, regex, key, unique

I have a rather generic question, I apologize it's lengthy. It's not just MySQL related and can be done in any scripting language but I did not find a better way to explain it. I have a list of unique words. Right now they are in a table in MySQL but implementation does not really matter, they can be in a text file just as well. Each word is exactly 6 chars. Words follow several slightly different formats. My goal is to shorten each word from 6 to 4 chars preserving uniqueness.

I googled the subject and all things like data minimization/optimization/collision did not provide useful results :( so here I am.

Here is an example of how it looks like:

```
--------------
words
--------------
word     short
------   ----
1A0001
1A0002
1A0003
AA0001
AA1001
AB0001
2BAC11
2BAC34
--------------
```

As you can see there are three formats that can be represented by the following generalized regular expressions:

```
^[0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$  - matches  1A0001 1A0002 1A0003
^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$  - matches  AA0001 AA1001 AB0001
^[0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]$  - matches  2BAC11 2BAC34
```

So based on the format different chars can be dropped to make the words 4 chars long and keep them unique.

```
^[0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$  - drop 1, 3
^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$  - drop 3, 4
^[0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]$  - drop 1, 4
```

I create values for `short` using `regexp/concat/substring` and a temporary table to do an update to `words`. As I said implementation is not really important for the explanation. It pretty much boils down to this:

```
select concat(substring(word,2,1), substring(word,4,3)) from words where word regexp '^[0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$';
select concat(substring(word,1,3), substring(word,6,1)) from words where word regexp '^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$';
select concat(substring(word,2,2), substring(word,5,2)) from words where word regexp '^[0-9][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]$';
```

This is how the table would look like in the end:

```
--------------
words
--------------
word     short
------   ----
1A0001   A001
1A0002   A002
1A0003   A003
AA0001   AA01
AA1001   AA11
AB0001   AB01
2BAC11   BA11
2BAC34   BA34
--------------
```

I can verify the uniqueness of `short` using:

```
mysql> select short from words group by short having count(short) > 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

This is very simplified scenario. In reality words are longer and there are more formats. Sometimes even though format is the same dropping same chars would create collisions, meaning two different `word` would result in a same `short` which is not acceptable. So `short` needs to be modified to become unique. The biggest difficulty comes from the fact that all the `word` are actually human understandable so `short` version should be human understandable as well and resemble the original `word`. This means I can't create some sort of hashing algorithm to ensure uniqueness of the short version, that's not enough, it has to be somewhat like the original word. Right now I'm thinking of replacing `0` with `O` and so on.

I guess you got a feel that this is more of a science question rather than an implementation question. The only important aspect of the implementation is performance. I'd like to have a good performance so I don't have to wait forever.

Have anybody seen anything similar?

Where would I start looking for a way to do it?

Comment: How many words? How many times will you need to go through this odd process?

Comment: it's in 5-digit range.... so you can say 100000.